What is legal in retrieving stolen property?
In another forum (next door to this one), someone in my local community made the claim (paraphrased here)

I encountered a person rummaging through my car and stole some things.
This person took off and I chased them down.  When I caught up with
them I physically beat them and made them give back not only my
property but everything else on their person, and then sent them on their
way.

In my opinion because the author chased the thief they could not claim self defense, and in fact they assaulted and robbed the thief (robbed because the author took property that was not just theirs).  Other people on the forum have supported the author and are taking a point of view of "technically it may have been a crime, but morally it is not" as there has been an upswing in property crime in my area and the police are being seen as to not be doing anything about it - so someone has to teach these thieves a lesson.
Is my interpretation correct?  And while I understand the desire to protect your property, is there a point at which "convincing" a thief to return it is no longer legal?
FWIW this is in New Mexico, and I am looking for answers relevant to this state.
Edit
To add on, I saw this random website about self defense in NM where it states in part (with my emphasis):

Self-Defense Law 101 in New Mexico
There are a couple of other key points to remember regarding the use
of force. Significantly, once an individual becomes justified to use
force, the right to use force may end during the encounter if the
danger to the individual ceases or the threat is disabled. NM UJI
14-5171. As a result, if the initial aggressor ceases the
aggression—for example, by fleeing or being knocked unconscious—your
right to use force ceases.


Do you want to know comparative jurisdictions worldwide, or are you interested in a specific country? Holding a suspected thief is often legal, but only if one calls the police rather than taking justice into the own hands. And violence may be acceptable to prevent flight, but not as punishment.

Closely related https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31510/stealing-my-own-property-back/31511#31511

@o.m. I'm looking for a US/New Mexico centric answer

@ohwilleke  There is also this one https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15869/40871 but neither of them really seem to cover the "assault" aspect.  I know that there would be a self defense aspect if all the actions all occurred on the original authors property, but the events occurred in something akin to LEO's "hot pursuit".  At the very least the author was irresponsible as they no idea if the thief was armed or had accomplices nearby, which would have completely changed the events.

@Barmar Physical self-defense isn't the only justification for using force. You can also use proportionate force to defend your property, even property other than your home, just not deadly force. You can also use force to make a citizen's arrest.

Your "someone has to teach these thieves a lesson" puts you morally in the wrong. It's not your job to do that, and it is morally wrong to take more than they stole to "teach them a lesson". That makes you a thief, and just a few small steps away is lynching.

Right, that's getting into vigilanteism. It's the job of the justice system to teach them a lesson. Being cynical is not a justification for taking it into your own hands.

@Barmar I agree with the vigilantism aspect.  But there are still a bionic of people justifying the actions.  Not much I can do about it.

Self-defence includes defence of property
So, chasing a thief and using reasonable force to regain your (or somebody else’s) property is legitimate self-defence.
Similarly, chasing a thief and using reasonable force to effect an arrest is permitted provided the crime is still in progress. Arresting a thief who stole the property yesterday must be left to the police.
However, once the protagonist starts to “beat up” the thief, they are no longer acting in self-defence as the force is no longer reasonable, its assault and battery. Similarly, taking things that aren’t theirs makes them a thief as well.

I'm not so sure about self defense still being legitimate when chasing a thief.  See the update I just made. The thief was fleeing at the time they were tackled.

@PeterM I think the fleeing aspect is only relevant if you're protecting yourself from physical harm. It doesn't apply if you're using force to try to recover your property, since the thief would always be fleeing in that case.

@Barmar I don't know if the interaction started with conflict and then the thief fled.  But given that the author discovered the thief already in their property, it is possible.
